# How can I print a particular thing from a linked list when they are stored together

Tags: java

I wrote the follow program that takes the IP address and PC name but when printing out I only want to print the IP address and not the IP address and PC1 as well. Below is my program.

```
package linked;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class Linked {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        workPls oks = new workPls();
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt( args[0]));
            socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            while(true)
                {

                    byte []buffer = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);

                    PlsWork  ok = new PlsWork(packet.getAddress(),"pc1");

                    oks.addNode(ok);
                    oks.print();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception error){
                error.printStackTrace();
            } 


    }

}

package linked;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class workPls {
    public LinkedList  List= new LinkedList();

public void addNode(PlsWork st){
    List.add(st);
}
public LinkedList getList(){
    return List;
} 
public void print(){
    System.out.println(List);
}
}
```

how can i be able to print out only the IP address.

Comment: Is C++ really a relevant tag? Please, don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you will need to iterate over the elements in the `LinkedList` to access individual fields. To make things clearer it is better to declare your class using generics like this:

```
public class workPls {
    public LinkedList<PlsWork> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addNode(PlsWork st){
        list.add(st);
    }

    public LinkedList<PlsWork> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void print(){
        for (PlsWork p: list) {
            System.out.println(p.getIp());
        }
}
```

Since you didn't provide the `PlsWork` class source code I am assuming there is a field named `ip` in it and an associated getter.

You will also have to format the output to your liking. The `toString` method of the `LinkedList` does some formatting for you, but to isolate the field as you want you have to do your own formatting.

I'm changing the variable name from `List` to `list` to use the Java standard and also to not confuse the variable name with the `java.util.List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

i see you have a `List` of class `PlsWork`. you haven't included that class in your code, but i assume it has 2 fields, i'll call them `address` and `hostname`.

i assume the `print()` method is the one your trying to fix here. often the best way to modify a list in java is to use streams. that's *Method 1* below. it's a bit of a mouthful. *Method 2* just takes the list in place and prints the `address` field.

```
public void print() {
    // Original
    System.out.println(list);

    // Method 1 using stream()
    final List<InetAddress> addresses = list.stream().map(PlsWork::getAddress).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(addresses);

    // Method 2 using the getter, but splits it across multiple newlines
    list.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getAddress()));
}
```

in general, there are some things about your code i'd seriously consider changing so it honors better java conventions.

- read and implement any standard java formatting
- don't use the capitalization conventions `thisClassFormat` or `ThisFieldFormat` (you got the conventions exactly backwards)
- declare generics for collection classes
- don't return `LinkedList` as the type: return `List` so you hide the concrete type